# How can I add multiple tags for one view directly in XML?

Tags: android, android-xml

As the question states I simply want to add more than one tag to an XML View. For example, say I want to set an array of strings AND a separate string from my resources. I know how to do them individually but I want to know if there's a way of attaching more than one tag to a view directly within the XML code.

**Edit:**

My plan was to have a LinearLayout (l#1) that contained a dynamic amount of of a different LinearLayout (l#2) and within that View there would be a Spinner and an EditText. I need one tag for the hint of the EditText and the other for the array of strings to populate the Spinner. In the entire layout there are a multiple l#1 each using l#2 to populate it dynamically and each needing different hints and string arrays based on what they are used for.

My next idea was to add a integer as a tag to represent l#1 and and use a Switch/Case block in my code to populate the children of l#2 with the right hints and string arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible in XML, but in code what you could do is create a custom object which holds the strings you require and set that as the tag.

```
class CustomTagObject {
    public List<Strings> strings;
    public String myString;
}
```

Then later

```
CustomTagObject tagObj = new CustomTagObject();
tagObj.strings = new ArrayList<Strings>("String 1", "String 2");
tagObj.myString = "String from resources";
view.setTag(tagObj);
```

If you explain why you want to hold these items as the tag, I may be able to help you find an alternative approach?

Comment: I've just added an edit to add more detail and a possible solution. Feel free to suggest a more efficient solution.

Comment: This solution works great. I'd forgotten you could attach any object as a tag. +1

Answer (score 0):

Above solution works, but the usage is wrong(it will add extra overhead on your end to manage the key/value map).

The better way to achieve above is to use an overloaded method of `setTag` which allows you to specify id associated with the value.

Method signature:

```
public void setTag(int key, Object tag)
```